# How to use foreach inside string in c#?

Tags: c#, html, foreach

I am trying to create a HTML Email Template with table in c# . For the same i used string and trying to concatenate the HTML tags. Now i have to add values from List as table data but not able to add the foreach loop inside string ..Below is my code..

```
EmailFormat += "<table><thead><tr><th>FirstName</th><th>LastName</th><th>Id</th><th>Date</th></thead>" 
+ foreach(Notification pReview in Review)
   {

   }
+ "</table>";
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foreach` is a *Statement*, not an *Expression*. You can't use statements inside expressions.

It' fairly easy to solve though:

```
EmailFormat += "<table><thead><tr><th>FirstName</th><th>LastName</th><th>Id</th><th>Date</th></thead>";
foreach(Notification pReview in Review)
{
  EmailFormat += /*anything you want to add...*/;
}
EmailFormat += "</table>";
```

Or better yet, use a [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) to construct your string.

Comment: Also note that in .Net 4.5 or later you can use [String.Concat<T>(IEnumerable<T>)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991828%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to concatenate all the `pReview.ToString()` values rather than explicitly using `foreach`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - It's not clear *what* is being concatenated but I'd imagine it involves a combination of instance properties and static string (to generate table rows markup). It guess it would be cleaner to use `StringBuilder.AppendFormat` for this task vs. mapping `pReviews` to strings.

Comment: Of course; I just meant that if they *were* doing `EmailFormat += Review;` then they could use `string.Concat()`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
EmailFormat += "<table><thead><tr><th>FirstName</th><th>LastName</th><th>Id</th><th>Date</th></thead>" + string.Concat(Review.Select(_ => _.{Anything})) +  "</table>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [StringBuilder](http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder) for the same task, as its better when concatenating strings. 
For example

```
        StringBuilder EmailFormat = new StringBuilder();
        EmailFormat.Append("<table><thead><tr><th>FirstName</th><th>LastName</th><th>Id</th><th>Date</th></thead>");
        foreach (Notification pReview in Review)
        {
            EmailFormat.Append("<tr><td>pReview.FirstName</td><td>pReview.LastName</td><td>pReview.Date</td></tr>");
        }
        EmailFormat.Append("</table>");
```

Then Convert `EmailFormat` to String for further use.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `StringBuilder` with his method append. this way you can build the string in parts se example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)